# C# XML Serializer - Serializing multiple nodes with same element names

Tags: c#

I have the following XML I am trying to produce:

```
<Tags>
   <Tag name="Motor" path="_types_" type="UDT_DEF">
      <Property name="Value"/>
      <Property name="DataType">2</Property>
      <Parameters>
      </Parameters>
      <Tag name="Alm" path="" type="Folder"/>
      <Tag name="Sts" path="" type="Folder"/>
      <Tag name="Comm" path="Alm" type="OPC">
         <Property name="Value"/>
         <Property name="DataType">6</Property>
         <Property name="OPCServer">Tag Server</Property>
         <Property name="OPCItemPath">ns=1;s=Alm.Comm</Property>
         <Alarms>
            <Alarm name="Alarm">
               <Property name="setpointA">1.0</Property>
            </Alarm>
         </Alarms>
      </Tag>
      <Tag name="Current" path="Sts" type="OPC">
         <Property name="Value"/>
         <Property name="DataType">6</Property>
         <Property name="OPCServer">Tag Server</Property>
         <Property name="OPCItemPath">ns=1;s=Sts.Current</Property>
      </Tag>
   </Tag>
</Tags>
```

I setup classes so I have a class for Tags which contain a Tag and I also have class for Alarms, etc.  It serialized fine until I got to the tag element "Comm", then it throws an error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Xml.dll 
>   Additional information: There was an error
>   reflecting type 'TagData.Tags'

How do I serialize my classes into XML when I have multiple element with the same name but different child elements?  My thought was to handle the serialization myself but I figured there was a better, easier solution.

Here is my C# classes:

```
/// <summary>
/// Contains all the tags.
/// </summary>       
public class Tags
{
    [XmlElement("Tags")]
    public List<Tag> ignTagList { get; set; }
}


/// <summary>
/// The tag itself.
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
public class Tag
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type;
    [XmlAttribute("path")]
    public string Path;
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name;
    [XmlElement("Property")]
    public List<Property> props { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Tag")]
    public List<Folder> folders { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Tag")]  // #### ERROR OCCURS HERE.  IF I RENAME THIS IT WILL SERIALIZE!! ####
    public List<OPCTag> opcTags { get; set; }

    public Tag()
    {
        this.props = new List<Property>();
        this.folders = new List<Folder>();
        this.opcTags = new List<OPCTag>();
    }

    public Tag(string Type, string Path, string Name)
    {
        this.props = new List<Property>();
        this.folders = new List<Folder>();
        this.opcTags = new List<OPCTag>();
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Path = Path;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

}


/// <summary>
/// Property data structure.
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
public class Property
{
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name;
    [XmlText]
    public string DataTypeValue;

    public Property()
    {
    }

    public Property(string Name, string DataTypeValue)
    {
        this.Name = Name;
        this.DataTypeValue = DataTypeValue;
    }

}


/// <summary>
/// Folder data structure.
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
public class Folder
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type;
    [XmlAttribute("path")]
    public string Path;
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name;

    public Folder()
    {
    }

    public Folder(string Type, string Path, string Name)
    {
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Path = Path;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

    public Folder(string Path, string Name)
    {
        this.Type = "Folder";
        this.Path = Path;
        this.Name = Name;
    }

}


/// <summary>
/// OPC tag data structure.
/// </summary>
[Serializable()]
public class OPCTag
{
    [XmlAttribute("type")]
    public string Type;
    [XmlAttribute("path")]
    public string Path;
    [XmlAttribute("name")]
    public string Name;
    [XmlIgnore]
    public IgnDataType DataType;
    [XmlElement("Property")]
    public List<Property> props { get; set; }

    public OPCTag()
    {
        this.props = new List<Property>();
    }

    public OPCTag(string Type, string Path, string Name)
    {          
        this.Type = Type;
        this.Path = Path;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.props = new List<Property>();
    }

    public OPCTag(string Path, string Name, UDTDataType DataType)
    {
        this.Type = "OPC";
        this.Path = Path;
        this.Name = Name;
        this.props = new List<Property>();
        this.props.Add(new Property("Value", ""));
        this.props.Add(new Property("DataType", ((int)DataType).ToString()));
    }

}
```

Comment: Did you try to copy your xml, and use `Edit/Paste Special/Paste XML as Classes` function in Visual Studio?

Comment: Throws *what* error?

Comment: I just tried to paste as XML.  It pastes but it doesn't look very clean and easy to follow.  I was hoping for an easier solution using what I already have (if possible).  The error is: An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Xml.dll

Additional information: There was an error reflecting type 'TagData.Tags'.

Comment: Even if you don't like how the class is "pasted", maybe you can compare it with what you have to see where may be the problem

Comment: Both folders and opcTags have the same XML tag name which is giving an exception.

Comment: Pikoh, I will check out the pasted XML further.  jdweng, that's the issue, I am looking for solutions to fix it.

Comment: There are many ways to do what you want. But the easiest thing is to change the xml format. Can you rename some `Tag` elements?

Comment: No I cant.  The XML is a fixed format that is used in another application.  I ended up keeping my current classes and overriding serialization.  It was actually pretty simple to implement.